# Contar distintas variantes de un valor en un recordset VBA - Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Tengo un `Recordset` en `VBA`, quiero contar cuantas variantes hay de un valor.

Es decir, lo que en una consulta `SQL` sería:

> SELECT COUNT(tag)
>
> FROM tabla
>
> GROUP BY tag

*Tabla* sería el `Recordset` y *tag* el valor que quiero saber cuantos tipos distintos hay.

Por ejemplo, si *tag* es: y1,y1,y1,y2,y3,y3,y4,y4,y5 quiero recibir un 5, ya que hay 5 valores diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

Para este tipo de operaciones es mejor usar los diccionarios.

He jugado con el objeto [Scripting.Dictionary](https://excelyvba.com/estructuras-de-datos-diccionario/)

Y ahora el código:

```
'---->IMPORTANTE!!!: Hay que activar la referencia a Microsoft Scripting Runtime <----!!!!

Dim RST As Recordset 'variable Recordset
Dim Dict As Scripting.Dictionary 'nuestro diccionatio

Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

Set RST = Application.CurrentDb.TableDefs("TABLA").OpenRecordset(1, 16)
RST.MoveLast
RST.MoveFirst


Do Until RST.EOF = True
    If Dict.Exists(RST.Fields("Tag").Value) = False Then
        'no existe, lo creamos
        Dict.Add RST.Fields("Tag").Value, 1
    Else
        'ya existe, no hacemos nada.
    End If

    RST.MoveNext
Loop

Set RST = Nothing

Debug.Print Dict.Count 'total elementos diferentes

Set Dict = Nothing
```

En mi caso, simulé una tabla en Ms-Access con el campo Tag e introduje los valores que pusiste en tu ejemplo `y1,y1,y1,y2,y3,y3,y4,y4,y5`, y la línea `Debug.Print Dict.Count` es la que devuelve el total de elementos diferentes. Ojo, porque los diccionarios dan muchísimo juego. En este ejemplo, me he limitado a hacer lo que pedías, pero en realidad en la parte del `Else` donde nosotros no hacemos nada, puedes decirle al diccionario que incremente la cuenta en 1 si el elemento existe.

Es decir, que con el objeto `Scripting.Dictionary` podrías obtener fácilmente lo siguiente:

```
TAGS DIFERENTES: 5

Tag    totales
 y1      3
 y2      1
 y3      2
 y4      2
 y5      1
```

Espero que puedas adaptar este código a tus necesidades :)